# DIVI contact module, need a way to pass the input field values in a GET request

Tags: php, wordpress, divi-theme

I have a bunch of input fields in my divi contact form module. It enables you to use the field values in an email like so

```
Hello %%name_field%%, thank you for asking %%question_field%%.
```

Now I need the ability to upload an image as an attachment, I was going to simply use custom php and html in a module, but I can't find how to make a custom module using xneelo as the hosting server, there is no includes/modules/ folder, only includes/module-extensions/ which isn't the same.

So I was wondering if it was possible to use the link field to make a get request using the input field values, eg link being /contact_processing.html?%%question_field%%+%%name_field%%. Then I could simply have a seperate page to upload the images

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You cannot pass images on the querystring ($_GET) they have to go in POST

Comment: yes that's why I was going to make a separate image upload page, but I need the values from the DIVI build contact form to be passed to the next page

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this @Samuel?